# React Functional Component: Immediately calling getElementById returns null

Tags: reactjs

If I add a timeout with 0ms then I can console log the elements that I have selected with `document.getElementById` but if I remove the 0 ms timeout they all return null. What's going on here?

```
import React from 'react';

const Warning: React.FC = () => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
    const invalid = document.getElementById("invalid");
    const confirmed = document.getElementById("confirmed");
    const warningBar = document.getElementById("warning-bar");
    console.log(confirm);
    console.log(invalid);
    console.log(confirmed);
    console.log(warningBar);
  },0);

  return (
    <div>
        <section className='warning-bar' id='warning-bar'>
            <div className='confirm' id='confirm'>Confirm</div>
            <div className='invalid' id='invalid'>Invalid</div>
            <div className='confirmed' id='confirmed'>Confirmed</div>
        </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export {Warning};
```

Comment: Why it happens? getElementById is executed before anything is rendered so you'll need to add the timeout or add it inside a lifecycle hook.

If for some reason you actually want a reference to the elements you should use the ref attribute on the element.

Comment: Similar question. Check the answer here. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843088/2878777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) and provide an empty dependencies array as a second argument, the callback function will be called after the component renders for the first time

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Warning: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
    const invalid = document.getElementById("invalid");
    const confirmed = document.getElementById("confirmed");
    const warningBar = document.getElementById("warning-bar");
    console.log(confirm);
    console.log(invalid);
    console.log(confirmed);
    console.log(warningBar);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <section className='warning-bar' id='warning-bar'>
        <div className='confirm' id='confirm'>Confirm</div>
        <div className='invalid' id='invalid'>Invalid</div>
        <div className='confirmed' id='confirmed'>Confirmed</div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is executing before your component load, so you need to render your dom first and get dom element after that

Comment: ok sounds good, how do i delay the execution until the dom has rendered without using a timeout?

Comment: You can use useEffect hook for that