# React Functional Component: How to access variables from outside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

I have simplified the issue below, I'm using the `useEffect` to ensure the dom has rendered before selecting the items, which works great and doesn't need a timeout before trying to get these elements, but then if I want to use these values in another component how do I access them?

The `printAll()` function cant find the variables.

````
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Warning: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
    const invalid = document.getElementById("invalid");
    const confirmed = document.getElementById("confirmed");
    const warningBar = document.getElementById("warning-bar");
  }, []);

  function printAll () {
    console.log(confirm);
    console.log(invalid);
    console.log(confirmed);
    console.log(warningBar);
  }

printAll()

  return (
    <div>
      <section className='warning-bar' id='warning-bar'>
        <div className='confirm' id='confirm'>Confirm</div>
        <div className='invalid' id='invalid'>Invalid</div>
        <div className='confirmed' id='confirmed'>Confirmed</div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};```
````

Comment: Have you considered using [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead? What do you intend to do with the elements?

Comment: I just want to show and hide them with `confirm.style.display = "none";` / block

Comment: Wouldn't `useState` be a better fit? `const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);`. You could call `setVisible` in event handlers, and in your render method, just check the value of `visible`

Comment: But why can't you put the variables outside useEffect using `let` instead of `const` and use them outside, pass through props? Also Pierre is right, you can do all that with useRef.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant access variable outside the block. If you want to access then you need to declare all variable outside the block of useEffect. You can do it in multiple ways like below.

Method 1: Declare variable outside.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Warning: React.FC = () => {
  let confirm;
  let invalid;
  let confirmed;
  let warningBar;

  useEffect(() => {
    confirm = document.getElementById("confirm");
    invalid = document.getElementById("invalid");
    confirmed = document.getElementById("confirmed");
    warningBar = document.getElementById("warning-bar");
    printAll();
  }, []);

  function printAll () {
    console.log(confirm);
    console.log(invalid);
    console.log(confirmed);
    console.log(warningBar);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section className='warning-bar' id='warning-bar'>
        <div className='confirm' id='confirm'>Confirm</div>
        <div className='invalid' id='invalid'>Invalid</div>
        <div className='confirmed' id='confirmed'>Confirmed</div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Method 2: Using useRef

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Warning: React.FC = () => {
  let confirm = useRef({});
  let invalid = useRef({});
  let confirmed = useRef({});
  let warningBar = useRef({});

  useEffect(() => {
    printAll()
  }, []);

  function printAll () {
    console.log(confirm.current);
    console.log(invalid.current);
    console.log(confirmed.current);
    console.log(warningBar.current);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section className='warning-bar' ref={warningBar} id='warning-bar'>
        <div className='confirm' ref={confirm} id='confirm'>Confirm</div>
        <div className='invalid' ref={invalid} id='invalid'>Invalid</div>
        <div className='confirmed' ref={confirmed} id='confirmed'>Confirmed</div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-lcci8)

Comment: Using method 1 i get this warning `Assignments to the 'resend' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect`

Comment: @Bill For that only i added 2 methods. U need to use second one by using useRef method.

Comment: the second example doesn't have any `getElementById` do I add this inside the {} from `useRef({})`

Comment: No need. At the time of rendering, react will assign the element reference to the ref variable, you can access directly in useEffect.

Comment: @Bill Demo link added for method 2

Comment: i feel we are so close,typeScript is now firing of this error ``` Type 'MutableRefObject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 237 more.ts(2322)
```

Comment: How did u initialized useRef? Can you share demo link or the code snippet.?

Comment: `let confirm = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);` made it work